# « Frapper de » ou « frapper avec » ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Instrumentally, "to hit with something" would have to be *frapper avec quelque chose*.

But as [this context](https://books.google.ro/books?id=HG1kAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA279&lpg=PA279&dq=%22je%20l%27en%20frappe%22&source=bl&ots=SjMVb4eQIT&sig=jp6y8pIj_f75xodNnL3bontzU0M&hl=ro&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZkZquvYPUAhVLuhoKHcaxB14Q6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22je%20l%27en%20frappe%22&f=false) suggests, *frapper* can (or could) also be used with *de* instead of *avec*.

Is *frapper de quelque chose* an archaic way of saying *frapper avec quelque chose*?

Comment: Looks like very old french ! 
"Frapper" the only verb used with "avec" et "de", but it is accurate that this form is more used in poems and old texts. 
Waiting for some more details, I can't answer this exactly

Comment: *de* is not an uncommon instrumental preposition. [Here](http://ow.ly/qJna30bW1Zh) is an ngram that shows that this particular collocation has been gradually shrinking, but is still apparently more common than "frapper avec" (in literary sources, anyway!).

Comment: @Orgoss: End of the 18th centuary, it's basically like modern French. Apparently you have never read Middle or Old French…

Comment: Stéphane Gimenez À chacun sa définition d'ancien ! Mais je l'avoue volontier, je n'ai jamais lu un texte "ancien" dans sa forme originale.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Les constructions syntaxique de ce genre sont *exactement* (après la prononciation) ce qui présente le plus de changement avec le français de cet époque. Je suis d'accord avec Orgoss, cet usage-ci est clairement archaïque en français contemporain (et je ne suis même pas sûr qu'il était considéré comme correct ou du moins courant à l'époque).

Comment: @Circeus: Je suis frappé de stupeur à entendre dire ça.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Bien entendu, je fais référence au fait que *frapper* est employé dans le contexte en question *avec son sens littéral*, ce qui n'est plus aussi usuel de nos jour. Toutefois je constate qu'il frappe de l'*index*, et non, comme je le croyais, avec un outil. IL s'agit là d'une exception (seule les parties du corps admettent cette construction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, *frapper de* is employed mostly in figurative senses, e.g. for juridical rulings, but also to mean "inflict" (frapper de stupeur "stupefy", frappé de folie "rendered mad") etc.

When the verb is used in its physical sense ("hit"), the default preposition is indeed *par*, **unless the instrument is a body part**, in which case, indeed, *de* is the regular construction. Other construction in French are specific to body parts, but not many involve alternate perpositions.

It is common cross-linguistically for constructions that involve body parts (usually because they involve grammaticalized [inalienable possession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inalienable_possession)) to have peculiar constructions applying to them.

Comment: Cool answer! Could there even be a double dose of this interesting notion of “inalienable possession” at work here since his index finger is tapping on the other person’s chest? Probably not!  Also probably unlikely, but could “inalienable possession” help explain why I see “de” more often than “avec” used in “Il mange/écrit de/avec la main gauche” whereas with tools (as you mention in a comment above) “mange/ écrit avec une fourchette/un stylo-bille” is more popular by far? (but then again, when it’s plural/non-specific “Il mange **avec** s/les mains/doigts” seems to sound better…go figure!)

Comment: Re: "double dose", no. the construction doesn't change regardless of what is being hit, thoug possession on the verb's patient does affect the construction: *il me tranche le/un bras* (lit. "he cuts me an/the arm off"), whereas other languages usually say the equivalent of "he cuts my arm off".

Comment: @PapaPoule Your other examples actually have an extra layer of complexity: normally you'll use *de* only **if the body part has an accompanying adjective**. Thus *Il lance d'une main sûre*, "with a steady hand", but *il mange avec ses doigts* "he eats with his fingers".

I believe the *de* construction (which applies to many verbs, as you note, but also in things like *se lever du bon pied*) there is better analysed as an adverbial construction applied to the verb rather than the [instrumental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_case) construction denoted by *avec*.

Answer (score 2):

Selon le [cnrtl](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/frapper), voici ce qui est dit à propos de *fraper de* :

§ I.B

> 2. [Double constr.] Frapper qqn ou qqc. de qqc. :
> 3. J'ai sollicité et obtenu du Garde des Sceaux un congé de deux mois pour raison de santé. Or, la loi frappe de nullité tout jugement rendu par un tribunal composé d'autres magistrats que ceux ayant siégé à la première audience. Courteline, Client sér.,1897, 3, p. 38.
>
> − Au passif. Être frappé de.Être l'objet d'(une décision administrative, juridique autoritaire). Frappé d'interdit. Tu n'avais, en effet, pas le droit de faire réparer ta maison (...) en termes techniques, elle était frappée d'alignement (Id., Client sér.,Balances, 1890, p. 134).Être frappé de Dieu (vx). ,,Recevoir un coup de la Providence`` (Littré). Éloigne-toi des femmes stériles, elles sont frappées de Dieu (Du Camp, Mém. suic.,1853, p. 257).

§I.C

> − Au passif. Être frappé de.Constater avec étonnement.
>
> 2. Si une considération de cette importance est au-dessus de la frivolité et de l'étroit égoïsme de la plupart des têtes françaises, au moins ne pourront-elles s'empêcher d'être frappées des changements survenus dans l'opinion publique. Sieyès, Tiers état,1789, p. 54.
> 3. [Double constr.] Frapper qqn de qqc.Provoquer chez quelqu'un un état émotif soudain. L'approche de la grande armée germanique frappa de terreur le monde musulman (Grousset, Croisades,1939, p. 258).Il frappait d'étonnement notre gang d'enfants prodiges parce qu'il était le meilleur sans être prodigieux (Sartre, Mots,1964, p. 189).